# Getting error "Activex Component cannot create Object" while using .NET dll in VB 6 Code

Tags: com, activex

HI,
I am deploying a VB6 application on client machine. The Application need to access code from a C#.NET dll. I created a COM object of the .NET dll and used it VB 6 using the side by side versioning (Registration free COM). It is running fine on the development machine
but on the client machine it is throwing an error "ActiveX Component cannot create Object"

I created two manifest files one for the VB application and the other one for the C# application. 
I embedded the C# manifest file in the C#.NET dll through visual studio 2008.

Am I missing some step.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you registered the .NET dll in the GAC?

Comment: Is your .Net assembly strongly named? You can check out UMMM tool here http://sourceforge.net/projects/ummm/